# I can't call a variable inside a def command in python tkinter

Tags: python

for some reason i can't call a variable inside a def command. hear is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
app = Tk()
app.title('movement')
canvas=Canvas(app,bg='Black',width=300,height=300)
canvas.create_oval(0,0,30,30,fill='Green')
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
n1 = 0
n2 = 0
n3 = 30
n4 = 30
n=100
def move_left():
    n1 = n1+n
    n3 = n3+n
    canvas=Canvas(app,bg='Black',width=300,height=300)
    canvas.create_oval(0+n1,0+n2,0+n3,0+n4,fill='Green')
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
    n = n+n
button_left = Button(app,text='->',command=move_left)
button_left.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

the error that appears is:

```
line 14, in move_left
n1 = n1+n
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n1' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: `tkinter` is unrelated. If you try the same code without it, you'd get the same error. You could actually remove the rest of the code and keep `n1=0..... ` to `n3 = n3+n`, to replicate the problem. (you might want to edit your code and do that, don't remove the error though)

Comment: If you want to write to a global variable inside of a `def` block, you need to make it available first via `global`. For example: `global n1`

Comment: You are creating an entirely new canvas, with an entirely new oval, each time the user clicks the button to move left. Are you _sure_ you want to do that? I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

the variable gets scrapped by Tkinter so to stop that happening you need to use 
this code when declaring the variable

```
n1 = IntVar()
n1.set(0)
```

and then to call the variable use:

```
n1.get()
```

note that if you want to use a string in a variable and the same error appears use

```
variable = StringVar()
```

and then the same code as before